# Windows 10: How do I turn off "Microsoft Start" completely?

Tags: windows-10

Reposting from [Windows 10: How do I turn off "Microsoft Start"?](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/how-do-i-turn-off-microsoft-start.591373/) as none of the answers there works for me, as I'm still seeing this:

[image]

Although I've disabled everything according to the answers there:

[image]

How can I completely disable it?
The only option from there is Hide each tiles, yet I've hide many tiles but they just keep coming:

[image]

Again, reposting from [Windows 10: How do I turn off "Microsoft Start"?](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/how-do-i-turn-off-microsoft-start.591373/):

> Another pointless update, another stupid bloatware nobody asked for. And they gave it a name that makes googling for help impossible, due to the results all relating to either startup or the start menu. How do I get this stupid newsfeed off my taskbar, and why does it know my city when I turned off location services?

Neither answer from this page work either:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-remove-the-news-feed-from-my-start-menu/9f4b50aa-87a6-4996-937d-6b15b24c720d

Comment: It knows your city by your IP address.

Comment: The Microsoft News App (Settings, Apps, Apps and Features) is not the same as the New and Interests Toolbar.  They are two different things.

Comment: I thought I wouldn't be able to find the answer but I did, just SO wouldn't allow me to answer my own question yet...

Comment: @xpt - Your screenshot is a picture of News and Interest.  I will trust that your solution does not involve disabling it. Your question is reopened.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course, if all of the news and interests functionality added as part of the ongoing evolution of Windows is not something a user wants, it can easily be disabled so that it doesn't appear in the taskbar. To do this, it's simply a case of right-clicking on a blank area of the taskbar bar, hovering the cursor over the 'News and interests' menu item, and selecting 'Turn off.'

[image]

In this sub-menu, it's also possible to choose whether to see an icon with text or just an icon on the news and interests button, to reduce the number of updates, and whether or not the tray will open when hovered over.

Comment: Thanks, welcome aboard, with my +25, :)

Comment: This seems to make no difference in memory or the number of services running.  Wish someone could describe how to permanently disable the service, or even identify it.  Click buttons in the UI as described only turns off the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Start, Settings, Apps, Apps and Features and scroll down to the Microsoft Start App.

Click on the App, select Uninstall and uninstall the App.

Restart and it should be gone.

Comment: As per your comment John, _"The Microsoft News App ,,, is not the same as the New and Interests Toolbar. They are two different things"_, please define what is Microsoft News App, Microsoft Start App, and what is New and Interests Toolbar first please. As I have an impression that we are talking about different things, which neither the original question's owner nor me knows how to name our "thing". That's why I posted lots of pictures, and the only thing that I found that links to it is the "Microsoft Start" (ref: 3rd pic, and I don't see that I have a Microsoft Start App)

Comment: The pictures do not necessarily tell what happened. There is a Microsoft News App. I do not use that but it appeared you did. There is a News and Interests Toolbar.  This is one is a duplicate for sure, and it is easy to turn off. Those posts were a while back

Comment: That's the first thing that I checked, and I'm sure I have neither Microsoft News App nor Microsoft Start App. _"There is a News and Interests Toolbar. This is one is a duplicate for sure, and it is easy to turn off."_ I don't know how/if that applies to my situation, but salvation mountain's answer solved my problem, so I'll accept his answer instead. thanks for your help.